# Why is 1/1/1970 the "epoch time"?

Tags: unix, time, epoch

Why is

> 1 January 1970 00:00:00

considered the *epoch time*?

Comment: Not sure why anyone thought this was subjective.  'Epoch' time is a standard time-stamping scheme.

Comment: n.b. this question was posted by @phoenix, I just corrected the grammar.

Comment: Today it was 380,000 hours ago

Comment: We should start counting time since this date, so we are now on year 44.

Comment: Today, right now, it is 1499969999! Its just approx. 8 hours to go!

Comment: [Why does Unix time start at 1970-01-01?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26205/44425)

Comment: @LeonardoRaele Yeah! then for example, World War II started on year 31 B.E.!

Comment: note that the NTP epoch lurches back 1 second every time there is a positive leap second, which is correct; UTC is broken when it comes to leap seconds (they're ignored).

Answer (score 488, accepted):

Early versions of unix measured system time in 1/60 s intervals. This meant that a 32-bit unsigned integer could only represent a span of time less than 829 days. For this reason, the time represented by the number `0` (called the *epoch*) had to be set in the very recent past. As this was in the early 1970s, the epoch was set to 1971-01-01.

Later, the system time was changed to increment every second, which increased the span of time that could be represented by a 32-bit unsigned integer to around 136 years. As it was no longer so important to squeeze every second out of the counter, the epoch was rounded down to the nearest decade, thus becoming 1970-01-01. One must assume that this was considered a bit neater than 1971-01-01.

Note that a 32-bit *signed* integer using 1970-01-01 as its epoch can represent dates up to [2038-01-19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), on which date it will wrap around to 1901-12-13.

Comment: Does 1/60 have anything to do with the frequency of the American power net?

Comment: It's the frequency of one of the oscillators on the system boards used at the time. It wasn't necessary for the oscillator to be 60Hz since it ran on DC, but it was probably cheap to use whatever was most common at the time, and TVs were being mass-produced then...

Comment: Actually, at the time, it was very common for computer clocks as well as RTCs to be synchronised with the US mains waveform because it was (is?) very reliable. It was multiplied to get the processor clock, and divided to get seconds for the RTC.

Comment: @MattHowells - why don't they upgrade the epoch to 2000 ?

Comment: @mafioso: Right, I'll set a reminder on my laptop for 2038-... 1901-12-13.

Comment: @JediKnight - Newer languages, such as [Fantom](http://fantom.org/) do! From their [DateTime](http://fantom.org/doc/sys/DateTime.html) class: 

    "Fantom time is normalized as nanosecond ticks since 1 Jan 2000 UTC"

Comment: @JediKnight This is speculation based on my own experiences as a developer: changing a standard takes time, and if your change doesn't take hold then you end up with [competing standards](http://xkcd.com/927/). The real solution to the epoch problem is 64-bit integers, not moving the epoch forward in time.

Comment: @Matt Howells, Could you get me url to this official standart, please!

Comment: @JediKnight Not to mention, there's not much of a reason to change the epoch time. Sure, you could save a few extra bytes, but would the end user  notice or even care? Plus, if you do change the epoch time, then every single program and library that relies on the timestamps being in reference to the 1970 time has to be updated.

Comment: @JediKnight Or it would be nice if it were 0000-1-1... except there was no year 0 between 1BC and 1AD. Or maybe the time of the big bang... except  we only know when that was to ±21 million years, and we might overflow a few integers. So maybe the decade that we developed computers is OK after all.

Comment: I'm expecting that in far future, earthlings will believe that the universe was created on 1 January 1970 00:00:00.

Comment: `> ...a 32-bit signed integer ...will wrap around to 1901-12-13."`
Am I missing something, is this not integer overflow and hence technically undefined (or more pragmatically, platform dependent)?

[Year 2038 Problem on Wikipedia concurs with @MattHowells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)
`> Times beyond that will "wrap around" and be stored internally as a negative number, which these systems will interpret as having occurred on 13 December 1901 rather than 19 January 2038.`

Thoughts?

Comment: @JediKnight Why not change the epoch to tomorrow?

Comment: @Michael It will break lot of existing systems

Comment: @Pradeep right, but JN was asking why they don't upgrade the epoch to 2000... if you're going to upgrade and break things, why not make it closer to today so at least it lasts longer?

Comment: @Michael I think there are better solutions, upgrading epoch to 2000 means our grad children will face the same problem, I would rather use 64 bit time_t and update old 32 bit systems to handle 64 bit time refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Solutions

Comment: I think the biggest thing people forget about updating it, isn't just that it represents "now" but it's stored in databases, files, etc and all those would have to be fixed, it's literally the worst possible idea other than changing it to letters (facetiously). That's why the *only* option is to make it unsigned as a hack or preferably give it 64bits of room to work with. Easier to change that than to edit petabytes of data.

Comment: The comment [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time#comment904870_1090878] by @Jörg W Mittag below also mentions the development year as a factor in the decision

Comment: Epoch's definition always felt about right to me, but since I was born a few days in 1970, maybe I'm biased (by a few days, obviously).

Comment: @Alexios. This is **utterly not true**. Computers have never in the history used the 60hz AC mains frequency as clock source. Quarz crystal oscillator, which are the first precise clocks since 1930, are referenced to the natural frequency of a quarz crystal due to the piezoelectric effect: 32768 Hz. Westinghouse engineers (1891), with and without Tesla, choose 60Hz (1891) (and 30Hz, 1893) as the best option for AC frequency, among he choices of 41.66Hz (General Electric, 1893) and 50Hz in Europe (AEG, Berlin, 1891).

Comment: Props to any engineer who, tasked with addressing Y2K problems, and thus fully aware of the stress and concern such an issue presented, went "OK, this will fix it... till 2038... I mean I could just use an unsigned... but f*** it that'll be someone else's problem"

Comment: Are computer clocks today still using 32-bit counters? With everything else in 64-bit now, it would seem quite unintuitive if this particular component is still on 32-bit. An unsigned 64-bit clock would allow computers to function for the next half a trillion years...

Comment: "Note that a 32-bit signed integer using 1970-01-01 as its epoch can represent dates up to 2038-01-19..."   Armageddon watchers refer to this as the sign of the times.

Answer (score 59):

[History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix%5Ftime#History).

> The earliest versions of Unix time had
>   a 32-bit integer incrementing at a
>   rate of 60 Hz, which was the rate of
>   the system clock on the hardware of
>   the early Unix systems. The value 60
>   Hz still appears in some software
>   interfaces as a result. The epoch also
>   differed from the current value. ***The
>   first edition* Unix Programmer's Manual
>   dated November 3, 1971 defines the
>   Unix time as "the time since 00:00:00,
>   Jan. 1, 1971, measured in sixtieths of
>   a second".**

Comment: Epoch time is 1 January 1970, not 1 January 1971.

Comment: @SteveHarrison It is, but it didn't start out that way

Answer (score 19):

## Epoch reference date

An [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) is a point on the timeline from which we count time. Moments before that point are counted with a negative number, moments after are counted with a positive number.

## Many epochs in use

> Why is 1 January 1970 00:00:00 considered the epoch time?

No, not *the* epoch, *an* epoch. There are **many epochs in use**.

This choice of epoch is **arbitrary**.

Major computers systems and libraries use any of at least a [couple dozen various epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing). One of the most popular epochs is commonly known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), using the 1970 UTC moment you mentioned.

While popular, Unix Time’s 1970 may not be the *most* common. Also in the running for most common would be January 0, 1900 for countless Microsoft Excel & Lotus 1-2-3 spreadsheets, or January 1, 2001 used by Apple’s Cocoa framework in over a billion iOS/macOS machines worldwide in countless apps. Or perhaps January 6, 1980 used by [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) devices?

## Many granularities

Different systems use different granularity in counting time.

Even the so-called “Unix Time” varies, with some systems counting whole [seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second) and some counting [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). Many database such as Postgres use [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond). Some, such as the modern *java.time* framework in Java 8 and later, use [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Some use still other granularities.

## ISO 8601

Because there is so much variance in the use of an epoch reference and in the granularities, it is generally best to avoid communicating moments as a count-from-epoch. Between the ambiguity of epoch & granularity, plus the inability of humans to perceive meaningful values (and therefore miss buggy values), use plain text instead of numbers.

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard provides an extensive set of practical well-designed formats for expressing date-time values as text. These formats are easy to parse by machine as well as easy to read by humans across cultures.

These include:

- Date-only: `2019-01-23`
- Moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):  `2019-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z`
- Moment with [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset): `2019-01-23T18:04:56.123456+05:30`
- Week of [week-based-year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): 2019-W23
- [Ordinal date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date) (1st to 366th day of year): `2019-234`

Answer (score 11):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#History explains a little about the origins of Unix time and the chosen epoch. The definition of unix time and the epoch date went through a couple of changes before stabilizing on what it is now.

But it does not say why exactly 1/1/1970 was chosen in the end.

Notable excerpts from the Wikipedia page:

> The **first edition** Unix Programmer's Manual dated November 3, 1971 defines the Unix time as "the time since 00:00:00, Jan. 1, **1971**, measured in sixtieths of a second".
>
> Because of [the] limited range, the epoch was **redefined more than once**, before the rate was changed to 1 Hz and the epoch was set to its present value.
>
> Several later problems, including the complexity of the present definition, result from Unix time having been defined gradually by usage rather than fully defined to start with.

Answer (score -11):

Short answer: Why not?

Longer answer: The time itself doesn't really matter, as long as everyone who uses it agrees on its value. As 1/1/70 has been in use for so long, using it will make you code as understandable as possible for as many people as possible.

There's no great merit in choosing an arbitrary epoch just to be different.

Comment: But why 1970 is chosen as the year.

Comment: Because Unix was developed in 1969 and first released in 1971 and it was thus reasonable to assume that no machine would have to represent a system time earlier than 1970-01-01-00:00:00.

Comment: As a developer of historical simulation games, it seems pretty silly that the designers of some time objects tend to assume all programs will only want to represent dates in the future or recent past. Of course, we can program our own representations, or work in an adjustment factor, but still.

Comment: The same pre-epoch issue applies to "practical" non-game uses, such as business spreadsheets, scientific data presentation, time machine UIs, etc.

Comment: @Dronz You have to take into account this was designed for a $72000  computer with 9KB of RAM which used transistors and diodes for logic gates as a CPU (no chips at the time!). So it wasn't "silly" to make the most basic thing that worked.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I understand why that was used circa 1970, and for types that will only ever represent computer system times. It's just unfortunate it makes those libraries less generally useful for other applications.

Comment: @Dronz I actually find the notion of "seconds since 1970" usable enough (sortable, simple, easy to do arithmetics with and can be stored in an int), but when it's not enough, most languages have a better encapsulation for dates and times. It's just still widely used because people like to use it, but an alternative is always around the corner.

Comment: OP is correct on a meta-level, the schemes we work out for time have always been fairly arbitrary.  The number of days in a year, number of days in the month, year "0", and the rules for leaps year are ... crazy.  Every system is just a series of crappy compromises made because it was the best they could do with the available technology and worked well enough for their immediate use-case.  Which is true of all engineering projects : )