# Why are dates calculated from January 1st, 1970?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there any reason behind using date(January 1st, 1970) as default standard for time manipulation? I have seen this standard in Java as well as in Python. These two languages I am aware of. Are there other popular languages which follows the same standard?

Please describe.

Comment: Another popular language following the same standard is PHP, its a fairly common time start point.

Comment: [Why is 1/1/1970 the "epoch time"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090869/995714), [Why does Unix time start at 1970-01-01?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26205/44425)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It is the standard of [Unix time.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds.

Comment: Do you know if Kernighan and Thompson every expressed a reason for choosing that moment beyond "It's a round number slightly before we started building the thing."?

Comment: It's the start of a year, it's in the zero timezone (Zulu). Both of those make the date formatting code simpler.

Comment: Doesn't count leap seconds?  I did not know that detail.  After thinking about it for a few moments, I can see why you'd do it that way, but man.  my world is shattered.  by 24 seconds.

Answer (score 86):

> using date(January 1st, 1970) as default standard

The Question makes two false assumptions:

- All time-tracking in computing is done as a count-since-1970.
- Such tracking is standard.

## Two Dozen Epochs

Time in computing is *not always* tracked from the beginning of 1970 [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). While that [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) is popular, various computing environments over the decades have used at least nearly [two dozen epochs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing). Some are from other centuries. They range from year 0 (zero) to 2001.

Here are a few.

> January 0, 1 BC
>
> January 1, AD 1
>
> October 15, 1582
>
> January 1, 1601
>
> December 31, 1840
>
> November 17, 1858
>
> December 30, 1899
>
> December 31, 1899
>
> January 1, 1900
>
> January 1, 1904
>
> December 31, 1967
>
> January 1, 1980
>
> January 6, 1980
>
> January 1, 2000
>
> January 1, 2001

## Unix Epoch Common, But Not Dominant

The beginning of 1970 is popular, probably because of its use by Unix. But by no means is that dominant. For example:

- Countless millions (billions?) of Microsoft Excel & Lotus 1-2-3 documents use `January 0, 1900` (December 31, 1899).
- The world now has [over a billion iOS/OS X devices](http://www.asymco.com/2013/11/25/one-billion-ios-devices/) using the [Cocoa (NSDate) epoch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/date) of `1 January 2001, GMT`.
- The [GPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) satellite navigation system uses `January 6, 1980` while the European alternative [Galileo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(satellite_navigation)) uses `22 August 1999`.

## ISO 8601

Assuming a count-since-epoch is using the Unix epoch is opening a big vulnerability for bugs. Such a count is impossible for a human to instantly decipher, so errors or issues won't be easily flagged when debugging and logging. Another problem is the ambiguity of granularity explained below.

I strongly suggest instead serializing date-time values as unambiguous [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings for data interchange rather than an integer count-since-epoch: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ` such as `2014-10-14T16:32:41.018Z`.

## Count Of *What* Since Epoch

Another issue with count-since-epoch time tracking is the time unit, with at least four levels of resolution commonly used.

- Seconds
  The original Unix facilities used whole seconds, leading to the [Year 2038 Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) when we reach the limit of seconds since 1970 if stored as a 32-bit integer.
- [Milliseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond)
  Used by older Java libraries, including the bundled java.util.Date class and the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.
- [Microseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)
  Used by databases such as [Postgres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).
- [Nanoseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)
  Used by the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

[image: Diagram showing different software counting from epoch by seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.]

Comment: I wonder what the dominant epoch is at this moment... did you base it on data?

Comment: @PascalVKooten Many different epochs are used in many different environments and software systems. So there is no one dominant epoch. My point here is to never assume the epoch. Know your data source. Best approach is for a data source to avoid the epoch problem entirely and just use ISO 8601 strings, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that there are many, but I'm curious to know if e.g. POSIX got more popular over time.

Comment: This is interesting and all but doesn't answer why 1970 was chosen to be the Unix epoch.

Answer (score 8):

why its always 1st jan 1970 , Because - '1st January 1970' usually called as "epoch date" is the date when the time started for Unix computers, and that timestamp is marked as '0'. Any time since that date is calculated based on the number of seconds elapsed. In simpler words... the timestamp of any date will be difference in seconds between that date and '1st January 1970' The time stamp is just a integer which started from number '0' on 'Midnight 1st January 1970' and goes on incrementing by '1' as each second pass For conversion of UNIX timestamps to readable dates PHP and other open source languages provides built in functions.

Comment: Why are dates calculated from January 1st 1970? Because dates are calculated from January 1st 1970. This is circular logic that doesn't answer anything.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any reason behind using date(January 1st, 1970) as standard for time manipulation?

No reason that matters.

Python's `time` module *is* the C library.  Ask Ken Thompson why he chose that date for an epochal date.  Maybe it was someone's birthday.

Excel uses two different epochs.  Any reason  why different version of excel use different dates?

Except for the actual programmer, no one else will ever know *why* those those kinds of decisions were made.

And...

It does not matter *why* the date was chosen.  It just was.

Astronomers use their own epochal date: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(astronomy)

Why?  A date has to be chosen to make the math work out.  Any random date will work.

A date far in the past avoids negative numbers for the general case.

Some of the smarter packages use the proleptic Gregorian year 1.  Any reason why year 1?
There's a reason given in books like Calendrical Calculations: it's mathematically slightly simpler.

But if you think about it, the difference between 1/1/1 and 1/1/1970 is just 1969, a trivial mathematical offset.

Comment: If 1/1/1 had been chosen we would have run out of seconds (2^31) by now.  As it stands, we face a Y2K like issue in 2038 for 32 bit operating systems.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: @Chris Nava: The folks that use 1/1/1 count days, not seconds.  2 billion days is about 5 million years.   Often they keep a (day,time) pair to maximize time resolution; there are only 86400 seconds in most days.

Comment: @S.Lott:  Yes.  I was just pointing out that since most software counts seconds (not minutes) since the epoch, 1/1/1 was to far in the past to be a reasonable start date.  Therefore, a more recent date was chosen as the computer epoch (and by association the start of the IT revolution. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Nava: "most"?  I assume by "most" you mean "Linux".  Other OS's don't work the same way Linux does.  The issue is that "reasonable" and "why 1/1/1970?" aren't easy questions to answer; most importantly, the answer doesn't matter.  "reasonable" is true, but it's not the reason **why**.  The reason **why** is something only Ken Thompson can answer.

Answer (score 5):

January 1st, 1970 00:00:00 am is the zero-point of [POSIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 3):

**Q)** "Why are dates calculated from January 1st, 1970?"

**A)** It had to be as recent as possible, yet include *some* past.
There was most likely no significant other reason as a lot of people feel that same way.

They knew it posed a problem if they placed it too far into the past and they knew it gave negative results if it was in the future. There was no need to go deeper in the past as events will most likely take place in the future.

**Notes:**
The mayans, on the other hand, had the need to place events into the past, since the had the knowledge of a lot of past, for which they made a long-term calender. Just to place all the routine phenomena on the calender.

The timestamp was not meant as a calender, it's an Epoch. And I believe the mayans made their long-term calender using that same perspective. (meaning they knew damn well they didn't have any relations with the past, they just had the need to see it in a bigger scale)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C (and its family). This is where Java took it too.