# System Time is 10 Digit , How?

Tags: java, windows, coding-style, operating-system

I have question about the current system time. I have software based on command line.
When I run that software, it shows me the time at both the start and end of execution. ie

- Start: `The current system time is: 1378258559`
- End: `The current system time is : 1378258570`

I do not know if the time is in seconds or minutes. How is the `1378258559` is calculated? The difference between the two numbers is `11`.

FYI, the current date and time on my system is: `04/09/2013 9:50 AM`

Comment: Try reading api for System.currentTimeinMillis() and see what the api says. I do not have right, otherwise i would have vote down for you.....Try reading first and then ask question.

Comment: Zero research effort.

Comment: Many thanks for you but the System.currentTimeinMillis() return 13 digit not 10 digit as i have saw in my system

Comment: Actually it is neither 10 nor 13 digits, it is 64 *bits.* You need to read the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [website](http://webnet77.com/cgi-bin/helpers/epoch.pl) has a calculator:

It is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 at midnight GMT.

The 11, is because something took 11 seconds.

Here's a post explaining why 1970 was chosen along with the definition:

- Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds.

[Why are dates calculated from January 1st, 1970?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533563/why-are-dates-calculated-from-january-1st-1970)

Comment: Many thanks for you but how it is since January 1st, 1970 at midnight GMT.? Just now i test it., or you mean that number is fix on  any system starting from since January 1st, 1970 at midnight GMT.

Comment: It's just a convenient starting place that was chosen for historical reasons. There's about 31.6 million seconds per year. So 1.37 billion is about 43 years.

Comment: 137 million is clearly not measured in seconds. See the linked calculator, and how the number mentioned in the original post clearly corresponds to the number of `seconds` (not milliseconds) from January 1st to the 4th September 2013.