# What kind of date time format is this ? i.e: "1551927028"

Tags: javascript, api, datetime, momentjs

I'm using an api from CryptoCompare, [here is the link](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN)

The response contains a field name published_on,I tried to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to convert to an appropriate date time format but it didn't work.

Does someone know the format or how to convert it to a normal datetime format.I'm using javascript

[image]

Comment: Related: [System Time is 10 Digit , How? [closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604246/system-time-is-10-digit-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This date is Unix time stamp. Since you are using moment, do the following to convert it to the date format

```
moment.unix(1551929623).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Please change the format whatever suits you.

Moment documentation link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/

Comment: really? why not simply `new Date(1551929623 * 1000)` - no crap library required

Comment: @Parakash Kandel i worked,thank you.@JaromandaX I still need to use moment since I use it to convert to from now

Comment: @jaromandaX It depends on how heavily you use the dates in your application. Since I saw @Cuong already uses the moment, I gave him the solution using moment. There is nothing wrong using `new Date(1551929623 * 1000)`.

Comment: Oh yeah - he tagged momentjs - didn't see that

Comment: It's time stamp

Answer (score 2):

This is called [**Unix time stamp**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16)

```js
console.log(+new Date())  // unix time stamp
console.log(new Date(1551929623 * 1000 )) //unix to normal date conversion
```

**On side note:** [**JS time stamp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is in miliseconds where as a [**UNIX time stamps**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) uses seconds. @JaromandaX thanks for info

Comment: Javascript does not use unix time stamp for dates

Comment: @JaromandaX but look at what MDN says https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: MDN is factually wrong - since clearly a Unix Time Stamp is seconds, and javascript time stamp is milliseconds

Comment: I'd say "unix to javascript" not "normal" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not much aware about that let me go through the tc39 specs and read what they say about it. anyways thanks for pointing out. will add it as side note.

Comment: @CodeManiac thank for the answer