# Why do the Number()/getTime() methods return the number of milliseconds since 1.1.1970?

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose/use of the Number() and getTime() methods returning dates to milliseconds since 1.1.1970?

[Number()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp)

[getTime()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

Comment: That's the Unix epoch. It's a commonly used reference point in time.

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090869/497418.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time or the link above

Comment: It's an easy way to compute date/time! Imagine that you need to compare two dates, it's easier to compare it in epoch time then in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, agree?

Comment: @EliasSoares Completely disagree. ISO 8601 date strings in UTC can be compared directly. The natural lexicographical order that string comparison does gives a proper ordering of time. Unix time doesn't have that property (nor can it easily be compared as numbers). Some values are ambiguous, such as `915148800500` which occurred twice because of a leap second and maps to both `1999-01-01T00:00:00.500Z` and `1998-12-31T23:59:60.500Z` in ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @Paulpro what is easier for a computer? Compare a if a number is greater then another, or compare strings lexicographically?

Also try to add 30 days in a ISO8601 string, again, what's easier for a computer?

Probably that was one of the reasons for using it in the past, where processor time, memory and program memory was very relevant.

Comment: `1999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` comes after `1998-12-31T23:59:60.500Z`, so comparing as strings gives the right result: `'1999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' > '1998-12-31T23:59:60.500Z'`, but their unix time equivalents give the wrong comparison result (`915148800000 < 915148800500`).

Comment: @EliasSoares I did not realize that when you said "it's easier to compare it in epoch time then in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format", you meant easier specifically for a computer and not for a human. Ambiguity and incorrect results aside, it is definitely easier for a computer to compare numbers than strings. I will not argue with that.

Comment: That's the point. I think that in that epoch, the unix time standard was a way to handle datetime in a faster way, though it's downsides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common convention used in programming as a standard to represent dates, that's free of timezone information and understandable in all situations.

To pull a quote from Wikipedia

> Epochs are generally chosen to be convenient or significant by a
>   consensus of the time scale's initial users, or by authoritarian fiat.
>   The epoch moment or date is usually defined by a specific clear event,
>   condition, or criterion—the epoch event or epoch criterion—from which
>   the period or era or age is usually characterized or described.

[Epoch Definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date))

[Another SO post that goes into better detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533563/why-are-dates-calculated-from-january-1st-1970/2533567)