# javascript - date difference should be zero but it is 18 hours

Tags: javascript, datetime

This one has stumped me.  It should be so simple I would think.  I am doing some very simple date subtraction in Javascript.  I am subtracting the same dates and I would think it would give zero hours, but it gives 18 hours.

```js
let inDate = new Date('Tue Aug 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)').getTime();
let outDate = new Date('Tue Aug 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)').getTime();

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = new Date(outDate - inDate);
```

```html
<div id='date'>

</div>
```

In case it produces different results based on where you are, the result I am getting is this:

`Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`

Comment: `outDate - inDate` results in `0` wherever you are, but `new Date(0)` prints differently depending on the timezone you’re in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to your `timezone`. If you convert to `GMT String` before print it the time will be correct. (Jan 01, 1969 00:00:00)

```
 new Date(outDate - inDate).toGMTString()
```

You should see the correct date.

```js
let inDate = new Date('Tue Aug 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)').getTime()
let outDate = new Date('Tue Aug 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)').getTime()

console.log(new Date(inDate - outDate).toGMTString())
```

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it was something super simple like that! :)

Comment: Was a typo. It's supposed to be `GMT String` instead of `UTC`

Comment: My browser, in the time zone shown, gave 21:00 hours as the time, like this: Wed Dec 31 1969 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Uruguay Standard Time) So, I'm in the day before, three hours short of the epic. Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @Dupocas looks like that function is deprecated.  toUTCString is working great for me.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString

Comment: Why is my result `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` ?

Comment: @deblocker for this answer, that is the desired and expected result

Comment: @deblocker subtracting 2 identical dates produces a zero date which is equal to the Epoch date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533563/why-are-dates-calculated-from-january-1st-1970/2533567