# Looping/Iterating over a sequence of dates yields weird numbers. What's their meaning?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

What gives in this example? How come it does not generate what I expect it to, and how can I change that behaviour?

`date_seq <- seq(ymd('2023-03-22'), ymd('2023-03-27'), as.difftime(days(1)))`

`[1] "2023-03-22" "2023-03-23" "2023-03-24" "2023-03-25" "2023-03-26" "2023-03-27"`

Then I loop through it `for(i in date_seq) print(i)`
and surprise, surprise:

```
...
[1] 19442
[1] 19443
```

No dates to be found!

You need to apparently use `for (i in seq_along(date_seq)) print(date_seq[i])` and voila!

```
...
[1] "2023-03-26"
[1] "2023-03-27"
```

Comment: I've not played with R, but this looks like a display/formatting issue.  E.g. if you take the number `19442` put it in Excel and format it as a date, it displays `1953-03-24`; which seems close to your input (albeit 70 years out)... So I suspect R has some base date from which this number is an offset.

Comment: Powershell `(get-date).AddDays(-19442)` returns 4th Jan 1970, so I suspect R's base date is `1970-01-01`.  Lots more info on "epoch" dates here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26391999/361842

Comment: @JohnLBevan Thanks! That made sense.

R is still weird af..
I'm supplying it a Date vector and it gives back a numeric in the for-loop x___x

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why the `for` loop changes the dates to numeric values, but you can prevent it by providing the date vector as a list, which preserves the date class.

```
v <- seq(ymd('2023-03-22'), ymd('2023-03-27'), "day")

for(i in as.list(v)) print(i)

[1] "2023-03-22"
[1] "2023-03-23"
[1] "2023-03-24"
[1] "2023-03-25"
[1] "2023-03-26"
[1] "2023-03-27"
```