# Basic javascript :getTime

Tags: javascript, html

can someoe explain to me this example, please:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_gettime

```
function myFunction()
{
var d = new Date();
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=d.getTime();
}
```

So there is variable that holds current date, putting some data into element with "demo" id.
But where on earth is something that tells me anything about:January 1, 1970? Is it something like mysterious date - known to everybody?

The second question is: why my fiddle doesn't work?:(
http://jsfiddle.net/jwUzM/3/

Thanks!

Comment: You never defined currentdate in your fiddle

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you're asking for `currentdate`, which doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: Don't use W3Schools. For language questions, [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) is the best reference, e.g. [time values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1). For examples and other information, the [MDN JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) is good, and the [User Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) is very helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question:**

Epoch time , is basically a representation of the number of seconds since  1 jan 1970 as others have pointed out .

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time) ..

**Second Question:**

You haven't declared currentdate but used it to insert value to the innerhtml . the line declares currentdate as a variable of type date.

var currentdate= new Date();

add this to your script to solve the issue.

Also you have -> var date = currentdate.getDate();, however ***date*** is not being used , its presence is no problem but remove it if you aren't gonna use it.

Comment: Glad to be of service !!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this links for January 1 ,1970
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Your fiddle contains an undefined variable 'currentdate'. That's why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In your Fiddle the currentdate variable is invalid I have updated that. Check it out..

```
var diag = "AM";
var currentdate = new Date();
var date = currentdate.getDate();
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
```

timer.innerHTML= currentdate.getDate();

http://jsfiddle.net/jwUzM/10/

Answer (score 0):

January 1, 1970 is a start of Unix Epoch.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

Comment: That doesn't sound right. `new Date()` is now, `new Date(0)` is epoch.

Comment: Yea, Agreed. This is what I meant about. Just had to say bout the integer parameter in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

About the first question: January first, 1970 is the start of [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Why it's January first, 1970 and not March 4-th, 1977, you can find in [this article](http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/news/2001/09/46651):

> At the time we didn't have tapes and we had a couple of file-systems
>   running and we kept changing the origin of time," he said. "So finally
>   we said, 'Let's pick one thing that's not going to overflow for a
>   while.' 1970 seemed to be as good as any.