# jQuery FullCalendar is returning the year 1970

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have the calendar initiated and and its renders properly.

I am using a select dropdown to jump to a month. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<select name="months">
    <option value="">Select a month ...</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('select[name="months"]').change(function() {
    var month = jQuery(this).val();

    // console.log(month);

    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2016, month);

});
```

For some reason when I change the month the Calendar is jumping to January 1970.

Any ideas?

Comment: `fullCalendar('gotoDate')` accepts a single date argument after it in a momentJS date format.

Would something like `'2016 '+month` work? Not familiar with momentJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the fullCalendar docs for `goToDate`:

> **gotoDate**
>
> *Moves the calendar to an arbitrary date.*
>
> .fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date ), where date can be a Moment object, or
>   anything the Moment constructor accepts.

When you change the date, you need to pass in a [moment.js date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/), or something that moment can convert to a moment date. Because your date isn't a valid 'moment' date, it's defaulting your selected date to '0' epoch time.

The code you'll need is as follows:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', [momentObjectHere]);
```

Fun fact: The reasons you see the year 1970 in the result, is that 1970 is '0' in epoch time. It's a way of representing time as a number. You can read more about [epoch time here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time) if you're interested.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/