# Why is the tm_year member in struct tm relative to 1900 rather than 1970 in C on macosx?

Tags: c, macos, time.h

I was trying out the examples in expert C programming while I encountered this problem. My program basically does one thing: use the standard `gmtime` function and see how many years has past since 1970.
Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *t = gmtime(&now);
    printf("%d\n", t->tm_year);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is **117**, the number of years past **1900**. This is unexpected because I checked `time()` and `man gmtime` beforehand and they both said they are relative to the Epoch time (1970-1-1 00:00:00):

```
time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch,
1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).
```

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html

```
The ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() functions all take an argument of data type 
time_t, which represents calendar time.  When interpreted as an absolute time 
value, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 
00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).
```

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html

According to the above description, my program should have returned **47** instead of 117. What is going on here?

```
macos sierra 10.12.5
Darwin 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
```

Comment: Because that's what the [doc says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html) also [online manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/)

Comment: Also the man page: `tm_year   The number of years since 1900.`

Comment: The section of the ctime(3) manpage you cite doesn't say anything about `tm_year`.  It describes how to interpret the `time_t` value, which is the *argument* to `gmtime(3)`.

Comment: I don't see a requirement from the C standard for a specific zero-date. Can you provide a reference? Why do you cite Linux man-pages for OSX?

Comment: Thanks for all the docs and man pages :D

Comment: ```tm_year``` is need to isolate the year in this century subtract 100. If need 2022 - can convert to string + "20" and back to integer as needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `tm_year` field is relative to 1900 on **all** POSIX-compliant platforms, not just on macOS.

The `struct tm` is designed for parsing, displaying, and manipulating human-readable dates. When it was created, dates were commonly written and even stored without the “19” part of the year number and the Y2K problem was around 25 years away. So the convenience of making `tm_year` directly printable as two digits, by making it relative to 1900, apparently seemed reasonable at the time.

Unix timestamps are relative to the “Unix epoch”, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. For the reasons why, [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090869/77567).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The `/usr/include/time.h` page on my mac says it is indeed relative to 1900.

Comment: @RainbowFizz If this answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The `tm_year` member of `struct tm` is relative to 1900 per the C library specification.   All compliant standard libraries use that.

> The `tm` structure shall contain at least the following members, in any order. The semantics of the members and their normal ranges are expressed in the comments  §7.27.2.1 4

```
...
int tm_year; // years since 1900
```

---

`time()` returns a `time_t` value "which may represent a
calendar time based on a particular epoch".  This is commonly 1970, Jan 1, 0:00:00 universal time.  *nix systems adhere to that.  This epoch of Jan 1, is not required by C and is not connected direclty to the epoch to the  `tm_year` member of `struct tm`.

Comment: I see. So `struct tm` is defined by the C standard and has no relation with the *nix conventions.

Comment: @RainbowFizz `time_t` is also defined by the C standard library.  It is the C standard allows for various implementations details such as what date/time is `(time_t)0`.  Many `*nix` compilers have further restricted  those details in a common fashion, like having `(time_t)0` as Jan 1, 1970.