# mysql virtual column incoherence wrt from_unixtime()

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, virtual-column

Got a table with a virtual column using from_unixtime():

```
CREATE TABLE aa (
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 epochmillis bigint,
 session_dt DATETIME(3) generated always as (from_unixtime(epochmillis/1000)),
 -- utc DATETIME(3) generated always as (convert_tz(from_unixtime(epochmillis/1000), @@time_zone, 'UTC')),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

I can't define an expression that uses variables (commented out), but from_unixtime() is using @@time_zone internally! That's unfair! LOL. Basically, this table returns session_dt according to the session timezone, which is more or less wrong depending on your opinion on requiring a session timezone, but just the same 'violation' as the variable I'm trying to use.

Ok, maybe you guessed what I'm doing: trying to get a stable UTC datetime(3) from an epochtimemillis column going well beyond 2038  (up to 3001 I think)(for the few date operations that could be easier on a datetime).

Just trying to get the best of both worlds (trivial epoch time, convenient zone-free datetime). In particular, I want to avoid the typical saving datetime in a writer's timezone and recuperating it in a distinct reader's timezone. By saving forcibly as epochtime, and with a generated datetime column that would give UTC, there would be no way to circumvent storing the proper instant.

TO BE CLEAR: I wish I could prevent from_unixtime() to choose the session's timezone and prescribe the timezone on the statement. All attempts at convert_tz are not desirable and only trying to undo that hidden choice.

What can I do to achieve my goal?

Reference (with suggested fix from accepted answer):
https://sqlize.online/s/Rf

Comment: which variables in the commented is none, but i don't see your problem, the fiddle doesn't clear nothing at all

Comment: The value `@@time_zone` can change (Winter-/Summer-time thing), and the definition of your table cannot change when this happens.  (see the list after: [Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html#:~:text=Generated%20column%20expressions%20must%20adhere%20to%20the%20following%20rules.%20An%20error%20occurs%20if%20an%20expression%20contains%20disallowed%20constructs.))

Comment: Luuk, this is understood, but the fiddle shows that virtual column strictly using from_unixtime() DOES change the value according to the @@time_zone internally from it's implementation. This is precisely why it's wrong and yet doesn't fail to create the virtual column. I don't want any timezone, I'm trying to undo what from_unixtime() did by converting to UTC (which should have been an arg to from_unixtime() if you asked me)

Comment: "what from_unixtime() did by converting to UTC"  But there is not timezone in unixtime, is there ?  (  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time )

Comment: Yes, several MySQL functions use the session time zone.  If you can't control that, or maybe even if you can, you are best off using a datetime column storing utc time.  I recommend ditching your epoch ms column.

Comment: fromunixtime(epochtimeseconds.millis) -> DATETIME in the session timezone.
The function returns a datetime, but in some timezone, not necessarily UTC. This is the problem. from_unixtime() is making a choice in secret that it will be the session's timezone, without asking. This is unstable and shouldn't even be allowed in a virtual column. Now, I'm glad I can still use it there, if I control the sessions's timezone, but my question is about finding a stable way to convert from_unxtime to a prescribed time zone on statement, not in a session variable.

Comment: And I'm saying MySQL is broken and makes that impossible, such that you are best off avoiding storing epoch seconds or using any of the session-dependent functions.  Just convert your data once into a datetime column storing utc.

Comment: well, it seems that simple in the schema, but drivers/clients don't play well. It leaves the definition of the instant up to the client and its handling of timezones, which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid with epochms, while avoiding timestamps and the 2k38 bug. Thanks for participating.

Comment: You can use utc_timestamp() for the current time in utc.  Getting clients to cope with utc datetime columns is its own question, which is often asked for different clients.  Note that you can have a generated epochmillis column if you store a utc datetime: https://dbfiddle.uk/KFASdOAE

Comment: Oh, now I remember you can do it with date_add (all the comparison/addition/subtraction functions ignore dst, which makes the choices for other things even more surprising).  If I have time I'll add an answer later

Comment: re this: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','SYSTEM','UTC'), CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','-05:00','UTC');` giving null in the reference fiddle, UTC is not a special name; it will work if you have named timezones loaded, but dbfiddle does not.  use `'+00:00'` instead of `'UTC'` and it will work whether or not the timezone tables are populated.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from epoch milliseconds to a UTC time with addition:

```
session_dt DATETIME(3) generated always as ('1970-01-01' + interval epochmillis*1000 microsecond),
```

That said, you really should just store session_dt in the first place, not use a generated column.  There's no good reason for storing dates as integers.  If you need the epoch milliseconds as a query result, you can get it from session_dt:

```
floor(timestampdiff(microsecond,'1970-01-01',session_dt)/1000)
```

Note that `utc_timestamp(3)` can be used to populate session_dt with the current utc time.  You should avoid functions like current_timestamp, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp that are affected by the session timezone.  You may have to figure out how to get your client to expect datetimes to be in utc, but that's worth doing anyway.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot.
dbfiddle is broken...
See instead 
https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/b22c2b06b9a00b9635fe65d782c22fc0/

Comment: Mariadb is not as "strong" as mysql on the from_unixtime(), but they both fail above year 3000. Your equivalent date_add is perfect.

But there is a good reason to store epochtime millis as I wrote in the question. In particular "By saving forcibly as epochtime, and with a generated datetime column that would give UTC, there would be no way to circumvent storing the proper instant."
This essentially restores the missing timestamp beyond 2038.

Comment: don't know what you mean by "circumvent storing the proper instant"; can you give an example?

Comment: The moment you get in/out those rendering of instant (ex in java: timestamp, zonedatetime, offsetdatetime, date), it involves choosing a timezone to convert to a zoneless datetime type, or a 32bits signed int epochtime in the mysql server. There are time zones of: the server os, the server config, the session variable, the client's jvm config, the client's os, and many iserver/client/url props telling which of 1 to 3 conversions could mistakenly occur until the client's driver gets the moment in/out. This is the insanity to avoid, me and all devs after me on my code.

Comment: When a dev cannot put/get anything but the epochmillis, there is no way to make convertion errors. And to perform zone-less date-time specific server-side WHERE or GROUP-BYs, there is this new config-insensitive generated columns to play with.

Comment: you'd do that exactly the same way: `insert into aa (session_dt) values (1970-01-01' + interval ? * 1000 microsecond)`.  not sure what the "And to..." is about?

Answer (score 0):

Converting time zones is deceptively tricky. One issue is if you store a date in the future, because it's impossible to know if some future policy will change a time zone, but you can only convert the time zone according to current policy. See https://codeopinion.com/just-store-utc-not-so-fast-handling-time-zones-is-complicated/ for more on this.

The only way you can make it clear in your database is store both the local time and UTC time as real columns (i.e. don't store the UTC time as a generated column), and also store the time zone of the local time, and the version of the timezone database at the time you last converted the local time to the UTC time.

```
CREATE TABLE aa (
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 epochmillis bigint,
 session_dt_local DATETIME(3),
 session_dt_utc DATETIME(3),
 local_tz_name VARCHAR(64),    -- e.g. "America/Toronto"
 tzdb_version VARCHAR(16),     -- e.g. "2022a"
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

That way if the timezone database changes for that locale at some time in the future, whoever is maintaining this database at that time has enough information to recalculate the UTC time according to the new timezone definition.

You can possibly fill in the `session_dt_local` as a generated column, since it can be done without referencing the timezone variable.

But you can't convert to UTC as a generated column. You must use a trigger for that. Since you have to write a trigger anyway, you might as well do both the local and UTC datetime calculations in one place. But that's up to you.

Comment: You say "you can possibly fill in the session_dt_local as a generated column, since it can be done without referencing the timezone variable." but I do not know of any function to go from epochtime to datetime without involving the session's timezone. If there is such a function, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: just to be clear, I have no need for any timezone, just generate the utc from the epochtime.

Comment: _"The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIME(), CURRENT_DATE(), and FROM_UNIXTIME() functions return values in the current session time zone, which is available as the session value of the time_zone system variable._ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I'm assuming you want `session_dt_local` to represent the local time zone. If that's not what you want, then you have to use a trigger after all.

Comment: Bill, I want to undo the "mistake of choosing sessions timezone" that from_unixtime() did. I wish I could just write from_uixtime(epochtime, 'UTC'). All seen attempts at handling timezones are only to try to undo a bad choice.

Comment: Indeed, well, from_unixtime() doesn't support that usage.